# Having trouble with IBM BlueMix when integrating Twilio and Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, twilio, ibm-cloud

I am having difficulties finding the correct module for Parse when deploying onto IBM BlueMix. I have tried the following:

```
 var Parse = require('node-parse-api').Parse;
```

This works locally because I used npm-install for parse but I am unsure of how to include this module on IBM BlueMix.

Comment: Did you mean npm install (instead of nom-install)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cf push <appname>` will deploy `node-parse-api` into Bluemix.

Add the `node-parse-api` in the `package.json` file for your node.js application

Example:

```
{
        "name": "NodejsStarterApp",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "description": "A sample nodejs app for Bluemix",
        "scripts": {
                "start": "node app.js"
        },
        "dependencies": {
                "express": "4.12.x",
                "cfenv": "1.0.x",
                "node-parse-api": "0.3.8"
        },
        "repository": {},
        "engines": {
                "node": "0.12.x"
        }
}
```